# Is following tautology: $((A∧B)→C)≡((A→C)∨(B→C))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I came across following problem:

> Is following tautology:
>   $((A ∧ B) → C) ≡ ((A → C) ∨ (B → C))$

I solved it like this:

> $(A\wedge B)\rightarrow C$
>   $=\neg(A\wedge B)\vee C$
>   $=(\neg A\vee \neg B) \vee C$
>   $=\neg A\vee \neg B \vee C$
>   $=\neg A\vee \neg B \vee C \vee C$ $\hspace{15pt}(\because C\vee C=C)$
>   $=(\neg A\vee C)\vee(\neg B\vee C )$
>   $=(A\rightarrow C)\vee(B\rightarrow C)$

So I concluded that it is a tautology.
But when I checked the answer it was given that it is not a tautology. So I checked wolframalpha and it also seem to give different truth tables for the two:

[$(A\wedge B)\rightarrow C$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BA+AND+B%7D+IMPLIES+C):
[image]

[$(A\rightarrow C)\vee(B\rightarrow C)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+IMPLIES+C%29+OR+%28B+IMPLIES+C%29):
[image]

Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth tables are the same, the variables are simply labelled in a different order in your tables.

Table 1 has $A$, $B$ then $C$, table 2 has $A$, $C$ then $B$.

Look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake.  The order of the rows in the tables are different, that's all.

The one False entry in the last column is when $A=T, B=T, C=F$ in both tables.

[Look here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+and+B%29+implies+C%2C+%28A+implies+C%29+or+%28B+implies+C%29)

Comment: Seems that this is related to [exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)). I always found them difficult to remember: $(p∧q) → r ≡ (p → r)∨(q → r)≡ (p→(q→r))$ and $(p∨q)→r≡(p → r)∧(q→ r)≡((¬p→q)→r)$    If I remembered these, I would have solved this problem in a moment without having any doubt.